# Getting the base url of the website and globally passing it to twig in Symfony 2

Tags: url, symfony, base-url

I'm making the switch from CodeIgniter to Symfony 2. 
Can someone please give me an example of how to:

- Get the base url (the url without the route specific parts)
- Globally pass this variable to the twig bundle so I can use it in every template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically setting the BaseUrl within configuration in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381809/dynamically-setting-the-baseurl-within-configuration-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Why do you need to get this root url ? Can't you generate directly absolute URL's ?

```
{{ url('_demo_hello', { 'name': 'Thomas' }) }}
```

This Twig code will generate the full http:// url to the _demo_hello route.

In fact, getting the base url of the website is only getting the full url of the homepage route :

```
{{ url('homepage') }}
```

(*homepage*, or whatever you call it in your routing file).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought this was the way to go but I only knew about the {{ path(..) }} function, leading to wrong results. {{ url }} is just what I needed.

Comment: what in case I am rendering the twig from symfony console command, lets say to generate email template, I need base URL. How do I do in that case.

Comment: There is a cookbook for that: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html

Comment: If I am not using *twig* then how can I rewrite this in *PHP* ?

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Not workingFatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "url" function in "default/template/extension/module/featured.twig" at line 5. in J:\xampp\htdocs\sites\opencart3020\system\library\template\Twig\ExpressionParser.php:574 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Even if this is not answering the exact question asked, it did help the asker at the time and even me right now (using Symfony 5/6).
Thanks for the help so I didn't complicate things more than necessary! ^^
For reference, here is the doc for the `url()` function: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#url

Answer (score 162):

This is now available for free in twig templates (tested on sf2 version 2.0.14)

```
{{ app.request.getBaseURL() }}
```

In later Symfony versions (tested on 2.5), try :

```
{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}
```

Comment: This can even be shortened to `{{ app.request.baseUrl }}` (it will locate the getter method and call that automatically)

Comment: @Colin O'Dell furthermore, it's even more appriopriate NOT TO USE the method calls in view - the view should not know what methods are in the object. Although it looks slightly diffrent in symfony, but +10 for that answer anyway.

Comment: If I am not using *twig* then how can I rewrite this in *PHP* ?

Comment: This does NOT work in later versions (tested on sf 2.5). The below answer `{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}` works!

Answer (score 60):

You can use the new request method `getSchemeAndHttpHost()`:

```
{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}
```

Comment: This function was introduced in Symfony 2.1

Answer (score 52):

Valid from Symfony v2.1 through v6.0+

If you want the base URL to a Symfony application, you should use `getSchemeAndHttpHost()` concatenated together with `getBaseUrl()`, similar to how `getUri()` works, except without the router path and query string.

```
{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost ~ app.request.baseUrl }}
```

For example, if your Symfony website URL lives at `https://www.stackoverflow.com/webapp/`, then these two methods return these values:

**getSchemeAndHttpHost**

```
https://www.stackoverflow.com
```

**getBaseUrl**

```
/webapp
```

*Note: `getBaseUrl()` includes the script filename (ie `/app.php`) if it's in your URL.*

Comment: And still valid with 5.4 (probably 6 too, but I don't have anything to test that on right now).  This should be the top answer.

Comment: There is a scenario which this doesn't work as expected.  That is cloud deployment in Azure for example where SSL is terminated at the load balancer.  Thus scheme will be http instead of https.

Answer (score 38):

Base url is defined inside `Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext`.

It can be fetched from controller like this:

```
$this->container->get('router')->getContext()->getBaseUrl()
```

Answer (score 20):

For Symfony 2.3+, to get the base url in a controller should be

```
$this->get('request')->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
```

Comment: `$this->container->get('request')->getSchemeAndHttpHost()`

Answer (score 16):

```
 <base href="{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}"/>
```

or from controller

```
$this->container->get('router')->getContext()->getSchemeAndHttpHost()
```

Answer (score 5):

Also for js/css/image urls there's handy function asset()

```
<img src="{{ asset('image/logo.png') }}"/>
```

This creates an absolute url starting with `/`.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer - does asset use the baseUrl after all? In my projects, it just prints a relative URL

Comment: in my project, asset uses the baseurl, but not host and scheme. it makes an absolute url starting with /. so it works fine as `<a href=`, or `<img src=` etcetera. It doesn't exactly answer the question but is the best option for most use cases.

Answer (score 5):

For current Symfony version (as of writing this answer it's Symfony 4.1) do not directly access the service container as done in some of the other answers.

Instead (unless you don't use the standard services configuration), inject the request object by type-hinting.

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

/**
 * The YourService class provides a method for retrieving the base URL.
 *
 * @package App\Service
 */
class YourService
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseUrl;

    /**
     * YourService constructor.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack $requestStack
     */
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->baseUrl = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current base URL.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseUrl(): string
    {
        return $this->baseUrl;
    }
}
```

See also official Symfony docs about [how to retrieve the current request object](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html).

Answer (score 3):

In Symfony 5 and in the common situation of a controller method use the injected *Request* object:

```
public function controllerFunction(Request $request, LoggerInterface $logger)
  ...
  $scheme = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
  $logger->info('Domain is: ' . $scheme);
  ...
  //prepare to render
  $retarray = array(
    ...
    'scheme' => $scheme,
    ...
    );
  return $this->render('Template.html.twig', $retarray);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing variable to template globally, you can define a base template and render the 'global part' in it. The base  template can be inherited.

Example of rendering template From the symfony Documentation:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  {% render "AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles" with {'max': 3} %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ dump(app.request.server.get('DOCUMENT_ROOT')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In one situation involving a multi-domain application, `app.request.getHttpHost` helped me out. It returns something like `example.com` or `subdomain.example.com` (or `example.com:8000` when the port is not standard). This was in Symfony 3.4.

Answer (score -3):

I tried all the options here but they didnt work for me.
Eventually I got it working using

> {{ site.url }}

Hope this helps someone who is still struggling.

Comment: Where does this come from? What does `site` contain?

Comment: That's from Timber and Wordpress.